# SQL Query depending upon current time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have some data in a table and I want to query it for data from it and depending upon when the query is is executed I want the query to take the current time stamp into consideration.

For example

```
declare @data table (id int, value nvarchar (50))

insert into @data values (1, 'First value')
insert into @data values (2, 'Second value')
insert into @data values (3, 'Third value')
insert into @data values (4, 'Fourth value')
```

Query 1

```
select * from @data
where value != 'First value'
and (value != 'Second value' and  '2012-08-30 23:59:59' between '2012-08-30 23:59:59' and '2012-09-15 23:59:59')
```

Query 1 Returns 'Third value' and 'Fourth value'

Query 2

```
select * from @data
where value != 'First value'
and (value != 'Second value' and  '2012-08-29 23:59:59' between '2012-08-30 23:59:59' and '2012-09-15 23:59:59')
```

Query 2 don't return any values, I want it to return
'Second value'
'Third value'
'Fourth value'

All help is appreciated 
Regards,
Jesper

Comment: When you say the current timestamp do you mean the time of execution? I can't quite understand what your trying to achieve :)

Comment: Yes I mean the time of execution. I want to exclude a row from the result during a period of time.

Comment: So you want to exclude rows from the result in a period of time (condition x) as well as allow exclude certain values from "condition x" - For example you want to select all values between 10AM and 11AM today, but if the value is "second value" it should be selected regardles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query will never return any values, as '2012-08-29 23:59:59' is not between the other two dates.

It will certainly never return 'Second Value', as you specifically exclude it.

I think you need to be a bit clearer on the logic you are trying to implement, maybe replacing the last AND with an OR NOT will get you closer, but this is a guess.

```
select * from @data
where value != 'First value'
and (value != 'Second value' OR NOT ( '2012-08-29 23:59:59' between '2012-08-30 23:59:59' and '2012-09-15 23:59:59'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `XOR` operator, but there is no such in SQL2008. You need to express `a XOR b` as `(a AND (NOT b)) OR ((NOT a) AND b)`.